# Hector Book (Advanced Tutorial)

Tags: cassandra, hector

is there any book for [hector](http://hector-client.github.com/hector/build/html/index.html), or any advanced tutorial?

I'm asking because as far as I can see official documentation is outdated, and there is a lot of undocumented methods.

Answer (score 2):

I can understand your frustration. The better solution for you is to understand the [API of Cassandra](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API/) and the [data model](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DataModel). Hector is just a wrapper. Then read some opensource projects using Hector.